# Rearrange a convergent alternating series to make it diverge [read desc.]

Tags: real-analysis

Can we re-arrange the alternating series $+1 -1 +0.5 -0.5 +\cfrac13 -\cfrac13  ... +\cfrac1m -\cfrac1m$ so it diverges ?

Is that possible? Any possible way?

Comment: $1+1/2+1/3+1/4$ then $-1$, then $+1/5+\dots +1/16$ then $-1/2$, then $+1/17+\dots +1/64$ then $-1/3$ go on with adding numbers bigger than $1$ and subtracting $1/n$.  Then you will get a number bigger than $1+1/2+1/2+\dots$ which is unbounded

Comment: The caps lock key is located near the 'a' letter!

Comment: @RGS THANKS ITS MUCH EASIER TO WRITE NOW!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier gLaD i CoUlD hElP

Comment: @ArnaudMortier seriously though, I think the original question was all in caps lock and has been edited to proper form

Comment: @RGS Yes I remember it was. But couldn't help, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

E.g. take positive terms until the partial sum $>1$, then one negative term, then more positive terms until the partial sum $>2$, then another negative term, etc.

Comment: The second group of elements do not have to add up to 2 I guess. They just have to be >1 , right ?

Comment: There are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking whether this series is conditionally convergent or if it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: No. I know its conditionally convergent. I am asking if it can re-arranged to be divergent. I could re-arrange it to reach ln(2) limit but not to diverge it so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if and only if the series is absolutely divergent. In this case it is, because the harmonic series diverges.

To be more precise:

> **Theorem:** let $u_n$ be a series of real numbers such that $\sum u_n$
>   converges but $\sum |u_n|$ diverges. Then for *any* $L\in \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ there is a permutation $\phi$ of $\mathbb{N}$
>   such that $\sum u_{\phi(n)}$ tends to $L$.